# Configuration Manager ignoring culture Info?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got the following class with a property 'amount' of type double

```
public class Transaction : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Amount", IsRequired = true)]
    public double Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(this["Amount"]);
        }
        set { this["Amount"] = value; }
    }
}
```

The value in my config file has a ','(Comma) as decimal separator instead of a '.'(dot) as we use the Dutch culture nl-NL(specified in web.config also). When parsing these 'double-strings' just in code it works fine. But when the Configuration Manager loads the section it throws an error specifying that 'amount' is not valid value. When changing the ','(comma) in the config to a '.'(dot) the Configuration Manager works fine.

**So my question is**: Is the Configuration Manager ignoring the culture of the website? Where do I specify the culture to use for the ConfigurationManager?